# URL fails with NSURLErrorDomain on iPhone, works fine in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I've got some code that is retrieving JSON data from a server on the 'net. I have tested extensively  in the simulator with great results. However, when I run the exact same code on my iPhone (simply switching the target device) it fails with NSURLErrorDomain, -1003.

After a little googling I found that this is a "CannotFindHost" problem. So I simply copied and pasted the URL into MobileSafari on my iPhone. Sure enough, it doesn't work, Safari states that "the server cannot be found". Typing the same URL into Safari on my MacAir works fine.

So apparently the URL lookup is failing on the iPhone but not my laptop. This is very strange, considering that the iPhone is connected to the laptop, that is is on the same WiFi router.

Now, ready for this?

When I turn off WiFi on the phone and use LTE, it works perfectly.

I cannot imagine what's going on here. I'm getting reports of this same problem from the field too. Can anyone offer a suggestion on why this might be?

Comment: What's the url is it pointing to valid domain name or it is working through /etc/hosts entry on your mac.

Comment: Hi Piyuesh - the URL is definitely valid, and NOT part of my etc file.

A simple lookup would explain why it would work on one *machine* and not another, but I don't see how it could explain that it *starts* working on LTE.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not 100% sure what's going on, but it appears to be limited to certain iPhones. People downloading the app fresh in the last day or two have no problems.

That seems to imply there's a cache on the iPhone that is the issue, and that it's cached on a per-connection basis.